# How to coordinate between UIViewController and UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am fairly new to iOS development, and i am not able to wrap my head around a concept..

I have two `UIViewController` classes - `ViewController` and `SecondViewController`. Initially, the `xib` file of `ViewController` class gets loaded, which contains only a `UIButton`. When this button is tapped, `SecondViewController` comes into play and it needs to load a view created by my `UIView` class called `ViewClass`. The `ViewClass` contains only a `UIButton`.

On clicking the button on the ViewController xib, all i get is a black blank screen, and I don't understand why loadView and viewDidLoad methods are being called so many times.. (the output is shown below)!!

Here's my code..

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize secondViewController = _secondViewController;

-(id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self)
    {
        NSLog(@"init of ViewController called");
        self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:self.secondViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    NSLog(@"presented");
}
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
-(void)loadView
{
    NSLog(@"loadView Called");
    self.myView = [[ViewClass alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myView];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"init of SVC called");
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"view WIll appear called");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"view did load called");
}
```

**ViewClass.m**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"init OF View Called");
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.titleLabel.text = @"Heyy";
        [self addSubview:button];   
    }
    return self;
}
```

and this is what i get on console..

```
2013-10-04 11:03:08.454 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xa894b30 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2013-10-04 11:03:08.503 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] init of ViewController called
2013-10-04 11:03:08.504 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] init of SVC called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.773 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] loadView Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.774 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] init OF View Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.775 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] view did load called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.776 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] loadView Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.777 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] init OF View Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.778 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] view did load called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.779 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] loadView Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.779 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] init OF View Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.780 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] view did load called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.781 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] loadView Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.781 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] init OF View Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.782 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] view did load called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.783 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] view WIll appear called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.783 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] loadView Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.784 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] init OF View Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.785 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] view did load called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.785 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] loadView Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.786 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] init OF View Called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.787 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] view did load called
2013-10-04 11:03:09.787 MVCPractice1[30957:a0b] presented
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job of `loadView` is to set `self.view` to a view.  When you receive the `loadView` message, `self.view` is nil.  It's your job to get a view from somewhere (by creating it in code or loading a nib) and store that view in `self.view`.

The `loadView` method **must** set `self.view` to a view before returning, and **must not** call t he `self.view` getter before setting `self.view`.  Try this instead:

```
-(void)loadView {
    NSLog(@"loadView Called");
    self.view = [[ViewClass alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Ok.. I got it.. But still i am not able to see the button in the ViewClass that i added.. I still get a blank black screen

Answer (score 0):

also Please make the initializations in ViewDidLoad when you are dealing with UIViewController which would be a good practise.

```
-(id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self)
    {
        NSLog(@"init of ViewController called");

    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"view did load called");
  self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
}
```

also change the loadView Method as rob mayoff has explained..

Comment: Ok.. Done.. But even after the changes, i get a blank screen after i click the button of ViewController.. Ideally i should get a view that a button that says "Heyy"